# Data Compression Through Polynomial Equations

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a new method of compressing data. What I want to do is take say a massive set of numbers, and then try and apply/generate polynomial functions to the data. I would then store the polynomial, with starting parameters, rather than each individual bit of data. This would mean at runtime, that the opening program would just use the polynomial to recreate the data.

My question: Are there any libraries or functions in Visual Basic .NET that will take say an array of data `{0, 2, 4, 6, ..., Large Even}` and return a "trendline" for it? Much like excel's graph trendline option.

Comment: Just as a note, this is not really a "new" method. In fact, it is one of the simplest way to compress smooth data (although it is not necessarily the most optimal). See e.g. [The Enhancement of Data by Data Compression Using Polynomial Fitting](https://archive.org/details/nasa_techdoc_19670028070).